# What does “thing” mean vs what is the meaning of “thing”?

Tags: grammar, expressions

In our ESL class a student asked teacher “what’s the meaning of “cough”?
The teacher replied “You might ask: What does cough mean instead of asking what is the meaning of cough?”
I asked why is the former incorrect and the latter is correct?
The teacher never answered the question.
I just want to know if both questions are correct or just the latter correct, if so, why?
Thank you

Comment: They're both correct and natural. Your teacher is wrong. The version your teacher suggests is perhaps more common, but the one the student used is also correct.